# Adding prettyPhoto Dynamically to img

Tags: php, str-replace

str_replace( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject)

I read that if $replace is array then each time it finds a new $search it uses a new value inside the array... but it is replacing "Array" instead...

```
foreach($image_name_array as $image_key => $image_value)
{
    $replace_img_fancy []= "<a href=".$this->config->site->data."articles/images/".$image_value." rel=prettyPhoto[gallery]> <img";
}


$ready_text = str_replace("<img", $replace_img_fancy,$data );
```

// on the output the "img" is being replaced by Array instead of the value

Comment: what is `$data` variable used as third paramter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I read that if $replace is array then each time it finds a new $search it uses a new value inside the array... but it is replacing "Array" instead...

Wrong. This works for `$search` or for `$replace` when `$search` is an array. You can do something like

```
foreach($image_name_array as $image_key => $image_value)
{
    $replace_img_fancy []= "<a href='/nyan.gif' rel=prettyPhoto[gallery]> <img";
    $search[] = "<img";
}

                               //array1  // array2
$ready_text = str_replace($search, $replace_img_fancy,$data);
```